# No session Found for current thread in cross-context request forward

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I have two web servlets (`Servlet-A` & `Servlet-B`) running within the same container.
Servlet-A is web application that has no access to the DB. It has a filter to forward certain requests to Servlet-B.
Servlet-B is a Spring/Hibernate application with access to the DB (using Hibernate).

When Servlet-A forwards a request to a controller in `Servlet-B`, the latter cannot create Hibernate session for that request, giving me error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
12:04:29,802 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
12:04:29,803 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:990)
```

It looks like the root context of the forwarded request is not recognized by `Servlet-B` and hence cannot grant it access to it's resources.

Here is what I am doing in `Servlet-A`
(1) Filter setup

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>CandidateProxyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.candidate.filter.CandidateProxyFilter</filter-class>                      
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CandidateProxyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

(2) `Servlet-B` filter code:

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
                ServletException {
        final RequestDispatcher proxyDispatcher = createProxyDispatcher(request);
        proxyDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Here the relevant controller code on the `Servlet-B`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String invokeView() {

    final Candidate candidate = candidateService.getCandidate(); // Crash !!!
...
}
```

`CandidateService` accessed the DB using Hibernate session, but for requests forwarded from `Servlet-A` it throws the above error.
For requests fired from `Servlet-B` context it is fine.
I just want to understand what is going on and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
It turned up that the configuration of `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in `Servlet-B` was ignoring all FORWARD request types by default:

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

All I had to do is to add the following to the filter:

```
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

The final setup is like that:

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>        
    </filter-mapping>
```